# How to hide navigation bar in pwa when opening external link

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, external-links

what is the best possible solution to hide navbar with three dots when opening external website in PWA app?

[image]

The case is that the app is already build, but when clicking the external link I wanted to open as standalone mode in app, so the only possible way to go back will be by using swipe gesture on android ;)

That is the code used for open this:

```
      class="space-button"
      on:click={() => {
        if (depObj.viewUrl) {
          window.location.href = depObj.viewUrl;
        }
      }}
    >
      BUTTON TO OPEN EXTERNAL LINK
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `webmanifest.json` the `scope` attribute defines what websites belong to your app. If the user navigates to a website not covered by the scope, it will be opened outside of the application window.

See more here: [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope)

Comment: so is it possible to add multiple scope to the app?